# KnockoutJs Visible doesn't work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want a `<td>` to be visible or invisible depending on a boolean value in my javascript.

My HTML is:

```
<!-- ... -->
<tbody data-bind="foreach: entries">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="visible: editable()">
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeEntry">Remove</a>
        </td>  
    </tr>    
</tbody>
<!-- ... -->
```

And my Javascript would be this:

```
//...
function TableEntryViewModel(){
    editable: ko.observable(false);
    //...
}
```

When it loads my data it only loads the first entry and then stops. Here's the error i get.

Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "visible: function (){return editable() }" Message: string is not a function

This isn't an exact replica of my programm, but if you make this work i'm sure you'll help me a lot: http://jsfiddle.net/CuppleKay/S6Hwa/

Comment: I have attempted to reproduce this and managed to hide the TD successfully.  That is to say, I could not recreate your issue.  Are you able to provide a simple JSFiddle reproduction of your issue?

Comment: Look into your console output, and you'll probably be seeing an error - cannot bind "editable()".  GoTo is correct, your "editable" value needs to be preceded by "this." in order to make it visible to your binding.

Comment: @Paul there was infact an error sorry: Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "visible: function (){return editable() }"
Message: string is not a function

Comment: That's to be expected.  Can you knock up a quick jsfiddle of your problem and edit your question to add a link to it?

Comment: kay that should work fine . well if there is more cshtml like loops on top of `<td>` update the code .

Comment: @Paul here I've made a similar programm: http://jsfiddle.net/CuppleKay/S6Hwa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I can see from your example what you're trying to do.  I've posted a modified version here:

http://jsfiddle.net/S6Hwa/2/

JavaScript:

```
function TableEntryViewModel(){
    var self = this;

    self.editable = ko.observable(false);

    self.removeEntry = function (row) {
        self.entries.remove(row);
    };

    self.entries = ko.observableArray([
        {name: "Hendrik", vorname: "Alex", adresse: "Southstreet", wohnort: "South", id: "239"},
        {name: "Hendrik", vorname: "Alex", adresse: "Southstreet", wohnort: "South", id: "240"},
        {name: "Hendrik", vorname: "Alex", adresse: "Southstreet", wohnort: "South", id: "241"}
    ]);
}

var model = new TableEntryViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

HTML:

```
...
<td data-bind="visible: $root.editable"><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeEntry">Remove</a>    </td>
...
```

Note that I needed to change your binding to `$root.editable`.  If you want to hide "Remove" on a row-by-row basis, then try the slightly different version:

http://jsfiddle.net/S6Hwa/3/

JavaScript:

```
function TableEntryViewModel(){
    var self = this;

    self.removeEntry = function (row) {
        self.entries.remove(row);
    };

    self.entries = ko.observableArray([
        {name: "Hendrik", vorname: "Alex", adresse: "Southstreet", wohnort: "South", id: "239", editable: ko.observable(false)},
        {name: "Hendrik", vorname: "Alex", adresse: "Southstreet", wohnort: "South", id: "240", editable: ko.observable(false)},
        {name: "Hendrik", vorname: "Alex", adresse: "Southstreet", wohnort: "South", id: "241", editable: ko.observable(false)}
    ]);
}

var model = new TableEntryViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

HTML:

```
...
<td data-bind="visible: editable"><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeEntry">Remove</a>    </td>
...
```

Note that because each entry in your observableArray contains an `editable` value, we don't need to use `$root.` anymore.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You sir are a hero! Thanks a lot for your help. It all seems to work fine now :)

Comment: @CuppleKay No worries.  I suspect your next move is to make name, vorname, and adresse (etc) into observables so you can edit them in the HTML and have the changes made back into your model.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is **incorrect**:

```
function TableEntryViewModel(){
    editable: ko.observable(false);
    //...
}
```

It should be either

```
function TableEntryViewModel(){
    this.editable = ko.observable(false);
    //...
}
//...
ko.applyBindings(new TableEntryViewModel());
```

Or

```
var TableEntryViewModel = {
    editable: ko.observable(false),
    //...
}
//...
ko.applyBindings(TableEntryViewModel);
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is what's going on.  See http://jsfiddle.net/W3vur/1/.  Whether or not the parenthesis are present doesn't seem to make a difference.  I think the OP needs to provide a sample...

Comment: neither of these were helpful @GôTô

Comment: @CuppleKay I updated to show the `applyBindings` method, maybe that can help. Otherwise can you provide some more code?

Comment: @CuppleKay [Corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/S6Hwa/1/). I changed the binding on editable (added $root because it was in a foreach binding), changed the declaration of editable with what is in my answer, and added ko.applyBindings

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if you are not providing the correct context. Are your `<td>` elements inside a KO `foreach`?

For example:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: items">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="visible: editable()">
      <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeEntry">Remove</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this example, the context within the `foreach` is `items` and not the parent ViewModel. If `editable` exists in the parent ViewModel then you need to provide that context like so:

```
<td data-bind="visible: $parent.editable()">
```